# What is the proper way to handle remote server disconnection?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

Almost all examples of work with remote services contain such code (this one was taken from Google IabHelper)

```
 mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            logDebug("Billing service disconnected.");
            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            logDebug("Billing service connected.");
            mService = getServiceFromBinder(service);
            ...
        }
    };
```

Why the field mService is always set to null? Is it wrong just to ignore onServiceConnected callback? In my experience reconnection usually happens after 1-2 seconds..
Google IABHelper even doesn't check mService for null despite the field is widely used, even is several async methods. And many my users get NPE in case of disconnection.
I want to patch IabHelper. The question is how..

What is a proper way to handle disconneсtion when the field mService is used inside async methods? Just ignore onServiceDisconnected and get RemoteExceptions? I thought about wait-notify approach but there is not guarantee that  reconnection will happen.
Any ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IabHelper example was updated to fix a number of bugs a couple of months ago, so first of all, be sure you have the latest version.  I have used an earlier version and made various fixes of my own, so I can't say whether the latest one actually fixes this.

Here is an issue that was filed a while back regarding it:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41610

The general approach would be to copy and edit IabHelper, and in your own copy, test for a null value at the top of launchPurchaseFlow().  Something like this:

```
//If the service has somehow disconnected, then we cannot make the purchase
if(mService == null) {
  result = new IabResult(BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE, 
    "Unable to buy item because billing service disconnected unexpectedly.");
if (listener != null) listener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
  flagEndAsync();
  return;
}
...
```

Also, at the end of onServiceDisconnected(), you will want to abort any async operation that may have been interrupted by the disconnection of the service.  Something like this:

```
boolean asyncWasInProgress = mAsyncInProgress;
if(asyncWasInProgress) {
  flagEndAsync();
}
```

Hope that is helpful.  IabHelper (at least the earlier version I used) has a number of bugs and so you can expect to come across this kind of thing, and such problems will need to be fixed when you do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The mentioned issue is my own:)

Comment: But checking for null in multithreading environment is not a right way. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: The documentation for ServiceConnection states that "Like many callbacks from the system, the methods on this class are called from the main thread of your process."  So, issues of multi-threaded execution should not apply in this case.  The ServiceConnection object remains active, and if and when the service is revived, its onServiceConnected() method will be called and mService will be set to non-null, and you'll be ready to process purchases again.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html

Comment: @akarimova it depends on how you do it. One technique is to check for null only from the main thread; no other new threads should check the variable for null (if you need to check for null then post a runnable onto the main thread). Other methods may include using volatile variables. But as Carl implied, being aware of which code snippet is executed on which thread will help.

Comment: Update: you can also catch null pointer exception. Locking (via `synchronized`) does seem to be the most fool-proof method but the main thread can't afford to wait to acquire the lock.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the downloaded V3 wrapper class IabHelper of Google to get rid of null pointer exceptions. I don't see an aspect of locking/synchronization problems in my project. There is no parallel processing except when the connection to the Billing service is interrupted, and setting an object to null won't take a long time.

Result can be downloaded from [github](https://github.com/pruedi/IabHelper/blob/master/IabHelper.java).

I also felt free to reduce the length of some methods and split them. I'm a fan of the approach that a methods body should not exceed a screen or page; helps to make code more readable.